# Get div refreshed just if something is inserted in db

Tags: php, ajax

I’m creating an chat application but I’m facing an HUGE obstacle.. I would like to know if it’s possible to get my data from my database to my website JUST if new data was inserted in there.

> What I have so far:

What I’ve so far is an div refreshing every X seconds using setInterval but to be honest I don’t want to use it like that because it is polling infinitely and that’s not user friendly, and the page gets slow.

Thank you in advance, I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: @Phil is that the only way?